# Random numbers in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want help on that I need to create Gridview (40 rows by 10 columns) on asp.net using vb.net and then generate and display random numbers between 1 to 50 in the gridview which should refresh every 2 seconds. Also need a button to turn on and off the refresh timer.  Can any one help or put me to the right direction?

Comment: For the auto-refresh function you may use the background worker class. Check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried putting gridview and linking it to empty Access database table and thought should create button click event to generate random numbers in the Access table which then refresh the Gridview but I think this is not the correct way as there must be some better way to do this.

Comment: Is there anybody on stackoverflow who knows how to do this???

Answer (score 0):

This stored procedure will shed some light and lead you to a path as you move forward. Am using MSSQL 2014 Express, I hope you can consider moving to MSSQL from Access.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcGetRandoms] -- your procedure name
AS

BEGIN
DROP Table RANDOMS 

CREATE Table RANDOMS  --your columns
(
One varchar(20),
Two varchar(20),
Three varchar(20),
Four varchar(20),
Five varchar(20),
Six varchar(20),
Seven varchar(20),
Eight varchar(20),
Nine varchar(20),
Ten varchar(20),
)

DECLARE @row int = 0
WHILE @row < 40 BEGIN -- your desired Rows
SET @row = @row + 1

INSERT INTO [dbo].[RANDOMS]
       ([One]
       ,[Two]
       ,[Three]
       ,[Four]
       ,[Five]
       ,[Six]
       ,[Seven]
       ,[Eight]
       ,[Nine]
       ,[Ten])
 VALUES
        (--Using NewID() function for first 3 rows
         ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 50)       
        , ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 50)  
        , ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 50)
        --random integer BETWEEN 0 AND 50  Using RAND() for the rest of the rows
        ,CONVERT(INT, (50+1)*RAND())
        ,CONVERT(INT, (50+1)*RAND())
        ,CONVERT(INT, (50+1)*RAND())
        ,CONVERT(INT, (50+1)*RAND())
        ,CONVERT(INT, (50+1)*RAND())
        ,CONVERT(INT, (50+1)*RAND())
        ,CONVERT(INT, (50+1)*RAND())
        )
END

-- to get the output that will be attached to your Gridview
SELECT * FROM RANDOMS

END

GO
```

-- On your Code Behind for the timer ('Handles Timer1.Tick)

```
    Dim sqlComRandoms As New SqlCommand
    With sqlComRandoms
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .Connection = conString
        .CommandText = "ProcGetRandoms"
    End With

    ' Create Data Adapter (Using the stored procedure Command created earlier)
    Dim DatadptRandoms As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlComRandoms)
    Dim datableRandoms As New DataTable

    DatadptRandoms.Fill(datableRandoms) 'data adapter to data table
    'Bind DataGridView using a Data Table intead of a Dataset
    DataGridView1.DataSource = datableRandoms
```

With this concept, I hope you will adapt it into MS Access and implement your solution. What works can be refined to something better with time.

Comment: Thanks Isaac.  I'll try this one.  Just one more thing that is there any way I can allocate threshold value to any cell of the Gridview (it can be multiple cells) so that when random value go above the threshold value the cell background colour get red.